# Wrap specific string with characters

Tags: sed, pattern-matching

For example, in a large file I might have:

```
This is a /16 text file
```

I'd like to change it to the following:

```
This is a [[[/16]]]] text file
```

Would like to match the exact string `/16`

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If your input contained `my address is 1.1.1.1/16` should it become `my address is 1.1.1.1[[[/16]]]`? Can `/16` appear multiple times on a line or only once?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have this in a file named `text.txt`

```
This is a /16 text file
This is another /8 text file
This is a /32 text file
```

I have found this command that can help you :

```
sed -i 's/\/\([0-9]\+\)/[[[\/\1]]]/g' text.txt
```

Comment: May be worth noting that `-i` and `\+` are non-standard GNU extensions. If you can assume GNU `sed`, you might as well do `sed -Ei 's|/[[:digit:]]+|[[[&]]]|g`

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -pi -e 's|(?<!\S)/\d+(?!\S)|[[[$&]]]|g' your-file
```

Would enclose the strings made of `/` followed by one or more (`+`) decimal digits (`\d`) that are neither preceded (`(?<!...)`) nor followed (`(?!...)`) by a non-whitespace character (`\S`) in `[[[...]]]`.

Replace `\d+` with `16` to match a literal `16` instead of any sequence of decimal digit. You may want to adapt the contents of the `(?<!...)` and `(?!...)` look-around operators depending on what you don't want (or want if you replace `!` with `=`) to find around that `/16`. Or remove them altogether if you want those `/16` to be `s`ubstituted even if they occur inside `http://16.1.2.3/` or `1/16` or `blah/16.12e-20` or `/1654321` or `[[[/16]]]`.

Comment: I have edited the question, want it to match only `/16`

Comment: @Proletariat, see edit.

Answer (score 1):

At the most trivial, this will change `/16` to `[[[/16]]]]` throughout `file`, leaving the original as `file.bak`:

```
sed -i'.bak' 's!/16![[[&]]]]!g' file
```

Some platforms may support using `-i` either without a suffix (the `'.bak'` here) or with an empty suffix (i.e. `''`) to edit in-place but without creating a backup. Remove the `-i` part entirely to write to *stdout* instead of editing the source file.

For example,

```
echo 'This is a /16 text file' | sed 's!/16![[[&]]]]!g'

This is a [[[/16]]]] text file
```

Per your instruction it takes no consideration of word boundaries: `80/160` will be replaced as `80[[[/16]]]]0`. Neither will the code consider similar-but-different instances such as `/8` or `/32`. Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/758652/edit) if such details must be considered.

Comment: Note for no-backup, in `sed` implementations that have `-i`,  the syntax is either `-i ''` (`-i` followed by a separate empty argument on FreeBSD and derivatives including macos) or `-i` not followed by anything in the same argument (GNU and most other implementations nowadays).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do exact match following command also might help you apart from other provided solutions;

```
 sed 's#/16#[[[/16]]]#g' yourfilename
```

The **explanation** is as follows:

- `sed` is a utility designed for making text modifications within an input stream, such as a file or pipeline.
- The `s` command is used to substitute or replace text. `#` is used as the delimiter in the `s` command to avoid conflicting with the `/` in the search pattern.
- `/16` represents the specific string you're seeking, and `[[[/16]]]` is what you'd like to replace it with.
- The `g` flag at the end means to perform the substitution globally.